# TypeError.undefined is not an object (evaluating _reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.constants.also

Tags: react-native

[image]

TypeError.undefined is not an object (evaluating _reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.constants.also

Comment: Are you trying to update to the newer version of RN camera ?

Comment: Please share update version name

Comment: RN Version I am using  "react-native-camera": "^3.11.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//import RNCamera  from 'react-native-camera';   // instead of 

import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';   //Use this 


 <View style={styles.container}>

            <RNCamera
                style={styles.preview}
                onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
                ref={cam => this.RNCamera = cam}
            >
                <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>BARCODE SCANNER</Text>
            </RNCamera>

        <View style={styles.bottomOverlay}>
```